# Pagination is not working on Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm trying to understand how Kendo UI grid works. This [the example for the Kendo website](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/remote-data-binding).

Somewhere one can find this configuration lines:

```
pageSize: 20,
serverPaging: true,
serverFiltering: true,
serverSorting: true
```

And this is the line that fetch the data

```
transport: {
             read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-  ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
        },
```

I wonder whether the above parameters are being sent to the server, i.e. a server side method should like this?

```
public list<type> MyServerSideMethod(inr pageSize, bool serverPaging,
                  bool serverFiltering, boll serverSorting)
{

}
```

In fact, I've applied the configuration, but the pager on my grid is still not working. That why I'm wondering whether the method in the server is expecting those values.

Thank for helping

Answer (score 0):

Define your read as a function and manipulate the parameters send to server

```
transport: {
            read: function (options) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(options)); // You can see what parameters send : check your console on paging 

               var commandOBJ=[{
                    Page: 1, // Once the first 20 item is loaded and you click for the next page you will have the page in "options" (should be like options.page)
                    PageSize:20 
                }];

                $.ajax({
                    url:"http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-  ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders",
                    data: {  }, // send your page info here 
                    dataType: "json", // your data return type 
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (result) {
                        options.success(result);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        options.error(result);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```